# Firebase Java Server to send push notification to all devices

Tags: java, android, firebase, server

I am trying to send a Push notification to my android device with the new Firebase service.
I registered and setup an app, also I put all the code needed to receive notification in the android app.
Via the Firebase Console I can send a notification to my app and it is received and shown.
Now I want to write a java standalone server, to send a notification to ALL devices. This is my current code:

```
final String apiKey = "I added my key here";
URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + apiKey);

conn.setDoOutput(true);

String input = "{\"notification\" : {\"title\" : \"Test\"}, \"to\":\"test\"}";

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(input.getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();

int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Post parameters : " + input);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

// print result
System.out.println(response.toString());
```

And this is the result that I am getting back from their servers:

```
{"multicast_id":6602141464107786356,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Unfortunately, simply removing the "to" tag doesn't work, I am getting a code 400 returned then.
I read that I need to register the device, send the device id to the server and save it there and then loop over all registered devices on the server to send the message.
Isn't there an easier way, to just send a message to all devices, just like in the console?

Your help is really appreciated, since I have been trying to get this to work all day long =(

Regards,
Dustin

Comment: You can check this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51172021/3073945

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.  Instead, what I would suggest is register all devices to the same topic and then you can message all the devices at once.  Here is the help documentation on this:

Send Topic Messages from the Server

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging

Comment: Yeah I thought about doing it this way as well, but I do not want to do any registration code in the app itself...
Any idea if that is possible somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by registration code in the app?  When your user starts your app, you can automatically register them to the topic.  In Android, it would look like this:
`FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("allDevices");`  You would put this in your onCreate method and when the app starts, they would automatically be registered.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help! That is exactly what I was looking for =)
How can I tag your answer as the best one? Already +1ed it

Comment: There should be a check mark under the down vote and score symbol on the left.  I see you checked it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

This solution send Push notification to Firebase using Apache HttpClient:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
post.setHeader("Authorization", "key=AIzaSyBSxxxxsXevRq0trDbA9mhnY_2jqMoeChA");

JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
message.put("to", "dBbB2BFT-VY:APA91bHrvgfXbZa-K5eg9vVdUkIsHbMxxxxxc8dBAvoH_3ZtaahVVeMXP7Bm0iera5s37ChHmAVh29P8aAVa8HF0I0goZKPYdGT6lNl4MXN0na7xbmvF25c4ZLl0JkCDm_saXb51Vrte");
message.put("priority", "high");

JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
notification.put("title", "Java");
notification.put("body", "Notificação do Java");

message.put("notification", notification);

post.setEntity(new StringEntity(message.toString(), "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
System.out.println(response);
System.out.println(message);
```

Comment: I get one error with your code: `HttpClientBuilder cannot be resolved`. How do I fix that error?

Comment: Have you added maven dependencies? 
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
 <version>4.5.2</version>
     </dependency>

Comment: What exactly is the `"to"` value in `message`?

Comment: @Geucimar i am getting this response after running this snippet.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=HTTP%2F1.1+401+Unauthorized+%5BContent-Type%3A+text%

Comment: This is now Deprecated

Answer (score 11):

Use below code to send push notifications to multiple devices :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.MulticastResult;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

public class PushNotifactionHelper {
public final static String AUTH_KEY_FCM = "your key ";
public final static String API_URL_FCM = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

public static void sendPushNotification(List<String> deviceTokenList) {
    Sender sender = new Sender(AUTH_KEY_FCM);
    Message msg = new Message.Builder().addData("message", "Message body")
            .build();
    try {
        MulticastResult result = sender.send(msg, deviceTokenList, 5);
        for (Result r : result.getResults()) {
            if (r.getMessageId() != null) 
                System.out.println("Push Notification Sent Successfully");
             else 
                System.out.println("ErrorCode " + r.getErrorCodeName());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
   }
  }
```

Note : use gcm.server.jar

Comment: Works, like charm Thanks.

Comment: what is the use of API_URL_FCM ..its not used in the code

Comment: Note - [gcm-server](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gcm/gcm-server) is no longer maintained for FCM - https://github.com/google/gcm/pull/272/files#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R3

Answer (score 9):

**Your JSON will be like this:**

> ```
>       {
>       "registration_ids": [
>                         "fcm token 1",
>                         "fcm token 2",
>                         "fcm token 3"
>                     ],
>       "data": {
>                 "message": "msg"
>               },
>       "notification": {
>                 "title": "App name",
>                 "text": " your msg"
>             }
>     }
> ```

```
public void sendGroupPush(Context context, ArrayList tokenlist, String message) {
            String msg = message;
            String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
            JSONArray regId = null;
            JSONObject objData = null;
            JSONObject data = null;
            JSONObject notif = null;
            try {
                regId = new JSONArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < tokenlist.size(); i++) {
                    regId.put(tokenlist.get(i));
                }
                data = new JSONObject();
                data.put("message", message);
                notif = new JSONObject();
                notif.put("title", title);
                notif.put("text", msg);

                objData = new JSONObject();
                objData.put("registration_ids", regId);
                objData.put("data", data);
                objData.put("notification", notif);
                Log.e("!_@rj@_group_PASS:>", objData.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.FCM_PUSH_GROUP_URL, objData,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.e("!_@rj@_@@_SUCESS", response + "");
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("!_@rj@_@@_Errors--", error + "");
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Authorization", "key=" + Constants.FCM_API_KEY);
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    Log.e("!_@rj@_@@PUSH_headrers", "::> " + params);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            int socketTimeout = 1000 * 60;// 60 seconds
            RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
            jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
            requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
        }
```

**public static String FCM_PUSH_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";**

Answer (score 6):

Here I have very simple solution for sending push message group as well 
   individual

```
public class FCM {
final static private String FCM_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

/**
* 
* Method to send push notification to Android FireBased Cloud messaging 
Server.
* @param tokenId Generated and provided from Android Client Developer
* @param server_key Key which is Generated in FCM Server 
   @param message which contains actual information.
* 
*/

static void send_FCM_Notification(String tokenId, String server_key, String 

message){


    try{
// Create URL instance.
URL url = new URL(FCM_URL);
// create connection.
HttpURLConnection conn;
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
//set method as POST or GET
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
//pass FCM server key
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","key="+server_key);
//Specify Message Format
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
//Create JSON Object & pass value
 JSONObject infoJson = new JSONObject();

 infoJson.put("title","Alankit");
infoJson.put("body", message);

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("to",tokenId.trim());
json.put("notification", infoJson);

System.out.println("json :" +json.toString());
System.out.println("infoJson :" +infoJson.toString());
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(json.toString());
wr.flush();
int status = 0;
if( null != conn ){
status = conn.getResponseCode();
}
if( status != 0){

if( status == 200 ){
//SUCCESS message
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
System.out.println("Android Notification Response : " + reader.readLine());
}else if(status == 401){
//client side error
System.out.println("Notification Response : TokenId : " + tokenId + " Error occurred :");
}else if(status == 501){
//server side error
System.out.println("Notification Response : [ errorCode=ServerError ] TokenId : " + tokenId);
}else if( status == 503){
//server side error
System.out.println("Notification Response : FCM Service is Unavailable  
TokenId : " + tokenId);
}
}
}catch(MalformedURLException mlfexception){
// Prototcal Error
System.out.println("Error occurred while sending push Notification!.." + mlfexception.getMessage());
}catch(Exception mlfexception){
//URL problem
System.out.println("Reading URL, Error occurred while sending push 
Notification!.." + mlfexception.getMessage());
}

}

 static void send_FCM_NotificationMulti(List<String> putIds2, String 
tokenId, 
 String server_key, String message){
    try{
    // Create URL instance.
    URL url = new URL(FCM_URL);
    // create connection.
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    //set method as POST or GET
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    //pass FCM server key
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","key="+server_key);
    //Specify Message Format
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
    //Create JSON Object & pass value

        JSONArray regId = null;
        JSONObject objData = null;
        JSONObject data = null;
        JSONObject notif = null;

            regId = new JSONArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < putIds2.size(); i++) {
                regId.put(putIds2.get(i));
            }
            data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("message", message);
            notif = new JSONObject();
            notif.put("title", "Alankit Universe");
            notif.put("text", message);

            objData = new JSONObject();
            objData.put("registration_ids", regId);
            objData.put("data", data);
            objData.put("notification", notif);
            System.out.println("!_@rj@_group_PASS:>"+ objData.toString());


    System.out.println("json :" +objData.toString());
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

    wr.write(objData.toString());
    wr.flush();
    int status = 0;
    if( null != conn ){
    status = conn.getResponseCode();
    }
    if( status != 0){

        if( status == 200 ){
    //SUCCESS message
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println("Android Notification Response : " + 
    reader.readLine());
    }else if(status == 401){
    //client side error
    System.out.println("Notification Response : TokenId : " + tokenId + " 
      Error occurred :");
    }else if(status == 501){
    //server side error
    System.out.println("Notification Response : [ errorCode=ServerError ] 
    TokenId : " + tokenId);
    }else if( status == 503){
    //server side error
    System.out.println("Notification Response : FCM Service is Unavailable  
   TokenId : " + tokenId);
    }
    }
    }catch(MalformedURLException mlfexception){
    // Prototcal Error
    System.out.println("Error occurred while sending push Notification!.." + 
   mlfexception.getMessage());
    }catch(IOException mlfexception){
    //URL problem
    System.out.println("Reading URL, Error occurred while sending push 
  Notification!.." + mlfexception.getMessage());
    }catch (Exception exception) {
    //General Error or exception.
    System.out.println("Error occurred while sending push Notification!.." + 
 exception.getMessage());
    }

    }
```

}

```
     Calling should be like that :



  public class TestFCM {
        static List<String> putIds;
        public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Just I am passed dummy information
    // DeviceID's

    String tokenId1 = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    String tokenId  = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
    String server_key ="<Server Key>" ;
    String message = "Welcome alankit Push Service.";

    putIds= new ArrayList<>();
    putIds.add(tokenId1);
    putIds.add(tokenId);

   /* for Group*/
    FCM.send_FCM_NotificationMulti(putIds,tokenId,server_key,message);  

    /*for indevidual*/
    FCM.send_FCM_Notification( tokenId,server_key,message);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

your code is perfect just recheck the registration id of the user whom you are sending the notification. In place of `to` use the users device regid.
It worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 3):

Android client side code should be:

```
//subscribe_topic with name "ALL"
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("ALL");
```

Server side:

```
string json = "{\"to\": \"/topics/ALL\",\"data\": {\"message\": \"This is a Cloud Messaging Topic Message\",}}";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  @Autowired
AndroidPushNotificationsService androidPushNotificationsService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> send() {


    JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
    // JsonArray registration_ids = new JsonArray();
    // body.put("registration_ids", registration_ids);
    body.put("to", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxjPwZpLgLpji_");
    body.put("priority", "high");
    // body.put("dry_run", true);

    JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
    notification.put("body", "body string here");
    notification.put("title", "title string here");
    // notification.put("icon", "myicon");

    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    data.put("key1", "value1");
    data.put("key2", "value2");

    body.put("notification", notification);
    body.put("data", data);

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(body.toString());

    CompletableFuture<FirebaseResponse> pushNotification = androidPushNotificationsService.send(request);
    CompletableFuture.allOf(pushNotification).join();

    try {
        FirebaseResponse firebaseResponse = pushNotification.get();
        if (firebaseResponse.getSuccess() == 1) {
            log.info("push notification sent ok!");
        } else {
            log.error("error sending push notifications: " + firebaseResponse.toString());
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(firebaseResponse.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>("the push notification cannot be send.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

you can get the classes from here:  https://github.com/AndreiD/testingpushnotifications

Comment: I checked your code but what I do not understand is why you are using ```HeaderRequestInterceptor``` whereas you can just use ```HttpHeaders``` to set up header and put in ```HttpEntity```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is Firebase Server Key for authorization purpose.
You just have to write http client code, you can use any programming language for that purpose.

Check out this [Github Repo](https://github.com/hammad-tariq/firebase-push-notification-server-java-rest-client-example). 
It has complete Java Rest Client project for sending firebase push notification from java server.

Answer (score 1):

The Use the below code to send push to multiple devices using FCM.

```
public void sendAndroidPush(String input) {
        final String apiKey = ServerKey or legacyServerKey;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + apiKey);

            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(input.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Post parameters : " + input);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;


            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }


JSONArray devices = new JSONArray();
        devices.put("Your Actual Device Token");

        JSONObject payloadObj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            JSONObject notifyObj = new JSONObject();
            notifyObj.put("title","Your Title");
            notifyObj.put("text", "Your Text");

            payloadObj.put("registration_ids",devices.toString());
            payloadObj.put("notification",notifyObj.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sendAndroidPush(payloadObj.toString());
```

Comment: it is returning Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send why ?