# FCM - Send Notifications using from within App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to send a notification via FCM without the Firebase Console. I want to send a notification from my application. I saw a comment saying:

You can send a notification by using cURL.

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=<API_ACCESS_KEY>" --Header "Content-Type: application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d "{\"to\":\"<YOUR_DEVICE_ID_TOKEN>\",\"notification\":{\"body\":\"Yellow\"} \"priority":\"10"}"
```

I want to send a notification to all of my application users. How do I send this command to the Google Service? Do you have any code for sending a notification?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You cannot send a message to "all devices", nor can you programmatically send a notification to "all users of your app". See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237559/how-do-you-send-a-firebase-notification-to-all-devices-via-curl) for your options

Comment: i look that pages. but i have not seen any code.do you have any code for send :) ?