# how to call fire base console in android app and send to notification in specific user app(device-fire base-device)

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications

I have created android application and I send notification to a particular person with firebase server. Help me please.

```
My code is:

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG="MyMessageservice";
    RemoteMessage remoteMessage;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
        String title=remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String message=remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String lick_action=remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
        Intent intent=new Intent(click_action);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri notificattionSound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationbuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationbuilder.setContentTitle(title);
        notificationbuilder.setContentText(message);
        notificationbuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationbuilder.setSound(notificattionSound);
        notificationbuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        notificationbuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationbuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationbuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: Have you getting any error?

Comment: no,how to send device to device notification

Comment: It's possible..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging

Comment: chek this link :[send a firebase notification to all device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237559/how-do-you-send-a-firebase-notification-to-all-devices-via-curl)

Comment: thanks to all now working fine i have using volley library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a notification to a specific device, i suggest you [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/). It is very simple to implement and it's free.

The benefit of this solution is not that you can send notification only to a specific user you can also send to a group of users and you don't need 3rd party servers to accomplish it.

Please take a look a this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWLRtwpJ6cQ).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you solved the problem regaring sending notifications?