# Push Notification to Android App using PHP

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create a push notification using PHP.
I have created my firebase account and add what's needs to be add in my android app.
I tested it by using the firebase console and it receives the notification.

Now I'm trying to create a push notification using PHP below is my code

```
 $apiKey = "apikey"; //Server Key Legacy
 $fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
 $token= 'singletoken';

 $notification = array('title' =>'test title',
                       'body' => 'hello message');

 $notifdata = array('title' =>'test title data',
                     'body' => 'hello',
                     'image' => 'path'
              );

 $fcmNotification = array (
                        'to'        => $token, 
                        'notification' => $notification,
                        'data' => $notifdata 
                    );


                $headers = array( 'Authorization: key='.$apiKey, 'Content-Type: application/json');

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
```

In my `Login Activity`, I use below code to get my register id

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
            device_key = instanceIdResult.getToken();
            Log.e(TAG, device_key);
        }
    });
```

And here is my `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
    super.onMessageReceived(message);
    sendMyNotification(message.getNotification().getBody());
}


private void sendMyNotification(String message) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    String channelId = "Default";


    Uri soundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My App")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Default channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());

}
```

}

I'm receiving notifications on my Android Emulator but in the real device I don't receive any notification.

Comment: what is the response code? if response code/status code is 200 the problem is in your NotificationService in android or else it is on your php

Comment: what do you mean by response code? @L2_Paver 
the $result variable display nothing as well.

Comment: I have example here but I use the topic to broadcast it to all subscriber to that topic. While you are using it to single Token only

Comment: I have updated my question and it returns unauthorized message error 401 @L2_Paver

Comment: did you use the Firebase Cloud Messaging Legacy server key not the Web API key?

Comment: @L2_Paver I edit the api key I successfully received a notification in my emulator but in the real device it says that it has an error `InvalidRegistration`

Comment: Try posting your android service code here and sufficient Logcat error logs. Every device and emulator have different token.

Comment: if you want to broadcast your notification to all device, refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237559/how-do-you-send-a-firebase-notification-to-all-devices-via-curl. gtg

Comment: **[You should not switch off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software)**. It could be a security risk! [Here is how to get the certificate bundle if your server is missing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

add error `output` before `curl_close`

```
echo curl_error($ch);
```

Comment: before closing the curl?

Comment: it returns no message

Comment: then you need to look at request in detail. I can advise only to dump request, data, headers before setting its to curl