# Sending Push Notifications to all devices without Firebase Console

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm making an app for work that's meant to be a portal for patrons using Java in Android Studio. I've set up Firebase Cloud Messaging, Authentication, and a Realtime database to store users. I can send out push notifications easily from the Cloud Console, but I was wondering if there was a way to send push notifications to all devices without using the console?

My reasoning is that I don't want someone in HR accidentally deleting a user, but I would like them to be able to send out push notifications for situations such as closings. Is there any way to do that, either through a remote push to all devices, or a restricted version of the console so that changes can't be made? I'm pretty new to this, so forgive me if this is a simple question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237559/how-do-you-send-a-firebase-notification-to-all-devices-via-curl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send notifications to all devices, provided all devices are **subscribed to a topic.**

You can create a **php** file that is responsible for sending the information to firebase using the **api token.**

If it has served you, I would appreciate your approval of my comment, regards.

**Notification.php**:

```
    $token = 'test'; // Topic or Token devices here
    $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

    // api key
    $serverKey = ''; // add api key here

    $notification = array('title' => 'Welcome StackOverFlow' , 'body' => 'Testing body', 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1');
    $data = array('extraInfo'=> 'DomingoMG');
    $arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification, 'priority'=>'high', 'data'=> $data);
    $json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. $serverKey;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);

    //Send the request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    //Close request
    if ($response === FALSE) {
     die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Is category the same as topic? Just for clarification since I'm not super familiar with the jargon yet. Like all devices that have used `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test")` will get the notification?

Comment: Where you put the token you put the topic and everyone who is subscribed will receive this notification

Comment: I correct the subject of category by subject, although for me it is the same

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) from a backend or other machine that you fully control.  It has an [API for sending messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) to devices where you have collected their device ID tokens.

There is no additional console or GUI for sending messages - you will have to write code if the console doesn't do what you want.