# How to send notification from one device to all available devices on Flutter using Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am creating a mobile application for my university.

I have added an **Admin Login** functionality where admins login and type notification content which is pushed to the following:

1. "Recent Updates Screen" as a List
2. Sent as a notification to all devices which have downloaded this application.

Can you help me in how notification can be sent to all devices so that all users know that there is something newly added to the "Recent Updates Screen" ?

Please do not recommend some hard-coded notification as it has to be entered in the text editing form by the Admin Person.

Comment: You to make sure you subscribe to a channel from all devices in firebase later on use that channel to send custom notifications

Comment: Sending a message **to** other devices to show a notification can only be done from a trusted environment, such as the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/notification/compose), [your development machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37376757), a [server that you control](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens), or something like [Cloud Functions/Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message). Also see:https://stackoverflow.com/a/38248296